# Location Manager Not Updating Outside ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, heading

I know it's been asked before but inspecting those questions did not solve my issue.

My `ViewController` deals with `CoreLocation` and has a location manager of it's own. It works fine, get's the location.

`ViewController` calls another class named `FootPath` which also requires it's own location manager.

I know of the singleton approach for a location manager but right now I have to make a lot of re-structuring so it's not an option.

FootPath's `init` method:

```
init(motionManager: CMMotionManager, expectedNavigationPattern: [StepDirection]) {
    self.expectedNavigationPattern = expectedNavigationPattern
    self.motionManager = motionManager

    super.init()

    self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 1
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
}
```

`FootPath` creates it's own location manager. I can see it allocated while debugging. But the heading does not get updated.

`Footpath` also conforms to `CLLocationManagerDelegate`.

This used to work, I checked the back-up and it's updating heading. Although I can't find the difference. I looked up via `FileMerge`.

I also tried the FootPath classes location manager allocation in a dispatch queue to target the main queue or restarted the device but it didn't change.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I am **not sure** this solution will fix your issue. But just try to delete your Location Manager initialization in your **FooPath** and **ViewController** class and create the Location Manager `constant` to your **AppDelegate** and get this `locationManager` from your class.

You can create the locationManager in your **AppDelegate** like this;

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

After that you can use initialized locationManager in your **custom class**.

```
private let locationManager = AppDelegate().locationManager
```

Just try this and please let me know if it works.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to work. I was also thinking about AppDelegate but not approaching it since it's a little bit bad practice. Although for the moment I've no other option. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks @emresancaktar it really worked. I was wondering since a day that why it is not working.